# Uninstall Ruby, rbenv and homebrew and reinstall Ruby on Rails with RVM on MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, rbenv

I'm very new to RoR specially on Mac. I have installed it many times on Ubuntu with RVM and I'm very comfortable with that. Here is what happened on Mac:

I went through instructions as explained here http://goo.gl/zsHcCC then when I got to the point to install Rails with " gem install rails " I got this error:

Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Now I want to roll-back everything and uninstall rbenv and it's ruby versions and reinstall the Ruby On Rails environment using RVM.

I tried to find how to uninstall Homebrew, RBENV and Ruby, but no success.

Thank you.
Sia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew or Rbenv are very good tools to have as a dev, I would think twice before removing either.

In this case I doubt they are at fault.

Can you confirm you have installed the GCC command line utils for OSX by running `$ xcode-select --install` in your terminal.

Here is a useful [post](https://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) explaining that process but I find that command generally works fine for me.

If this succeeds what does your `$ gem install rails` output next?

Comment: Thanks NibbleX, It solved the issue, I used RoR before a little bit and I used RVM instead of rbenv and I found it easier to work on that. I wonder if at this stage of setting up my RoR environment I can roll back and go with RVM?

Comment: Glad you are up and running now :)

You could rollback using `$ brew unlink rbenv ruby-build; brew uninstall rbenv ruby-build` and reinstall Ruby using RVM.

I would urge you to stick with rbenv as it is much easier to manage multiple versions on an application-by-application basis. I switched away from RVM a few years ago and haven't looked back!

Comment: At the end I decided to keep rbenv and get use to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very new you and you don't need specially the last version of Ruby. You can use Rails Installer http://railsinstaller.org/fr-FR.

To uninstall brew https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md

Comment: Thank you, I definitely want to use a version manager, but I found rbenv a bit confusing.